# Erro ao iniciar MariaDB no CentOS7

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

Bom dia.
Tenho um servidor dedicado rodando CentOS7 e o MariaDB parou e não consigo reiniciar o serviço.

```
[root@new ~]# mysqld start
2018-01-17 13:31:10 140236707752192 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB) 
starting as process 19665 ...
mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2018-01-17 13:31:10 140236707752192 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Quando eu verifico o status o retorno é esse:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
       └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-01-17 13:12:01 UTC; 24min ago
Process: 10903 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 10891 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10888 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 10903 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: 2018-01-17 13:12:01 
139872544868608 [Note] InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: 2018-01-17 13:12:01 
7f369d59c900  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: InnoDB: Error number 
11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: InnoDB: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br mysqld[10903]: 2018-01-17 13:12:01 
139872544868608 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't open './ibdata1'
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 13:12:01 new.webgocontent.com.br systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

Quando uso o mysqld --user=root os serviços funcionam, mas não posso deixar assim. Preciso que o serviço volte a rodar.
Alguém já teve este problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/starting-and-stopping-mariadb-automatically/

Comment: eu fiz o que este link pedia, mas nada disso resolveu